# How to check if a batch is finished and apply calculations for every finished batch in Kusto?

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql, kusto-explorer

The following question have been asked by me before but it didn't have a suitable description based on the data sample provided.

I have the following data which I randomally generated in kusto:

```
let data = datatable(BatchNumber: string, Timestamp:datetime, Power1:int, Power2: int, Speed1: int, Speed2: int, Enabled1: bool, Enabled2: bool)
        [
         "620214P", datetime(2022-02-18 10:00:00 AM), 100, 200, 50, 80, false, true,
         "620214P", datetime(2022-02-18 10:01:00 AM), 100, 200, 50, 80, true, true,
         "620214P", datetime(2022-02-18 10:02:00 AM), 100, 200, 50, 80, false, true,
         "620214P", datetime(2022-02-18 10:03:00 AM), 100, 200, 50, 80, true, true,
         "620214P", datetime(2022-02-18 10:04:00 AM), 100, 200, 50, 80, false, true,
         "620214P", datetime(2022-02-18 10:05:00 AM), 100, 200, 50, 80, true, true,
         "620214P", datetime(2022-02-18 10:06:00 AM), 100, 200, 50, 80, false, true,
         "620214P", datetime(2022-02-18 10:07:00 AM), 100, 200, 50, 80, true, true,
         "720214P", datetime(2022-02-18 10:08:00 AM), 100, 200, 50, 80, false, true,
         "720214P", datetime(2022-02-18 10:09:00 AM), 100, 200, 50, 80, true, true,
         "720214P", datetime(2022-02-18 10:10:00 AM), 100, 200, 50, 80, false, true,
         "720214P", datetime(2022-02-18 10:11:00 AM), 100, 200, 50, 80, true, true,
         "720214P", datetime(2022-02-18 10:12:00 AM), 100, 200, 50, 80, false, true,
         "720214P", datetime(2022-02-18 10:13:00 AM), 100, 200, 50, 80, true, true,
         "720214P", datetime(2022-02-18 10:14:00 AM), 100, 200, 50, 80, false, true,
         "720214P", datetime(2022-02-18 10:15:00 AM), 100, 200, 50, 80, true, true,
         "720214P", datetime(2022-02-18 10:15:00 AM), 100, 200, 50, 80, false, true
        ];
```

What I am trying to achieve here is to check when is the batch finished.
Please Note that the batch number in this case is a string which is **unique**. **The logic to achieve what I want is to get the last value of a batch number and check the value after it. If the next value is different from the one before then the previous batch is finished.** So in this case, batch number = "620214P" is finished but batch number = "720214P" not yet. However, in this case I shouldn't be checking for a specific batch number because we are getting values in real time. The script should know by itself when is the batch finished probably by doing by checking if the batch number is finished based on the logic I explained above (in bold), and when it knows that the batch number is finished, it should project this batch number, Batch_Date (in this case for batch number = "620214P", the date is 2022-02-18 10:07:00 AM), and total power (which is based on some calculations **only for this finished batch**)

For example expected result for BatchNumber = "620214P",

[image]

In this case, once the script knows that batch number = "720214P" is also finished a new record will be added with this batch number. Let us assume that one addition row was added to the dataset with batch number = "820214P", so the expected result would be:

[image]

So everytime the script knows that a batch is finished it should directly add it as a new record as shown in the screenshots, projecting the new batch, the date when it was finished and some calculations specifically for the newly added batch (from the period it started until the period it ended).

I am a bit confused how can I do this in Kusto? If it is possible or not ? I don't know if there is a better and efficient way to do it?

Here is a screenshot of the table which I need (to use materialized-view):

[image]

Comment: @DavidדודוMarkovitz Here is the new post, where I changed the data sample and modified the description. Thank you for your help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

##### 1

Once again, a questionable data sample...
If **BatchNumber** is an increasing number with **p** at the end, all we need to do it removing the **p** and converting the rest to a number.
For this answer I will assume that is not the case.

###### 2

To find the latest **BatchNumber** we will now use [arg_max()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/arg-max-aggfunction) with **Timestamp**.
The completed batches are assumed to be those with **BatchNumber** different from the latest **BatchNumber**.

###### 3

Please note that for both this solution and the previous one, if the events does not come in order, we might see undesired result, such as a batch displayed before it was actually completed or completed batch that is not displayed.
Eventually, the report would be consistent.

##### Demo

```
.create table data (BatchNumber:string, Timestamp:datetime, Power1:int, Power2: int, Speed1: int, Speed2: int, Enabled1: bool, Enabled2: bool)
```

---

```
.create-or-alter materialized-view data_mv on table data
{
    data
    | summarize BatchData = max(Timestamp), TotalPower = sum(coalesce(Power1,0) + coalesce(Power2,0)) by BatchNumber
}
```

---

```
.create-or-alter materialized-view data_BatchNumber_of_max_Timestamp_mv on table data
{
    data
    | summarize arg_max(Timestamp, BatchNumber) by dummy = 1
}
```

---

```
.create-or-alter function completed_batches_f ()
{
    let latest_BatchNumber = toscalar(data_BatchNumber_of_max_Timestamp_mv | project BatchNumber);
    data_mv
    | where BatchNumber != latest_BatchNumber
}
```

---

```
.ingest inline into table data <|
620214P, datetime(2022-02-18 10:00:00 AM), 100, 200, 50, 80, false, true
620214P, datetime(2022-02-18 10:01:00 AM), 100, 200, 50, 80, true,  true
620214P, datetime(2022-02-18 10:02:00 AM), 100, 200, 50, 80, false, true
620214P, datetime(2022-02-18 10:03:00 AM), 100, 200, 50, 80, true,  true
620214P, datetime(2022-02-18 10:04:00 AM), 100, 200, 50, 80, false, true
```

---

```
completed_batches_f
```

| BatchNumber | BatchData | TotalPower |
| --- | --- | --- |

---

```
.ingest inline into table data <|
620214P, datetime(2022-02-18 10:05:00 AM), 100, 200, 50, 80, true,  true
620214P, datetime(2022-02-18 10:06:00 AM), 100, 200, 50, 80, false, true
620214P, datetime(2022-02-18 10:07:00 AM), 100, 200, 50, 80, true,  true
720214P, datetime(2022-02-18 10:08:00 AM), 100, 200, 50, 80, false, true
720214P, datetime(2022-02-18 10:09:00 AM), 100, 200, 50, 80, true,  true
720214P, datetime(2022-02-18 10:10:00 AM), 100, 200, 50, 80, false, true
720214P, datetime(2022-02-18 10:11:00 AM), 100, 200, 50, 80, true,  true
```

---

```
completed_batches_f
```

| BatchNumber | BatchData | TotalPower |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 620214P | 2022-02-18T10:07:00Z | 2400 |

```
.ingest inline into table data <|
720214P, datetime(2022-02-18 10:12:00 AM), 100, 200, 50, 80, false, true
720214P, datetime(2022-02-18 10:13:00 AM), 100, 200, 50, 80, true,  true
720214P, datetime(2022-02-18 10:14:00 AM), 100, 200, 50, 80, false, true
720214P, datetime(2022-02-18 10:15:00 AM), 100, 200, 50, 80, true,  true
720214P, datetime(2022-02-18 10:15:00 AM), 100, 200, 50, 80, false, true
```

---

```
completed_batches_f
```

| BatchNumber | BatchData | TotalPower |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 620214P | 2022-02-18T10:07:00Z | 2400 |

---

```
.ingest inline into table data <|
520214P, datetime(2022-02-18 10:16:00 AM), 100, 200, 50, 80, false, true
```

---

```
completed_batches_f
```

| BatchNumber | BatchData | TotalPower |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 620214P | 2022-02-18T10:07:00Z | 2400 |
| 720214P | 2022-02-18T10:15:00Z | 2700 |

---

**Update for the OP**

```
let data_BatchNumber_of_max_Timestamp_mv = toscalar(data | summarize arg_max(Timestamp, BatchNumber) | project BatchNumber);
data
| summarize BatchData = max(Timestamp), TotalPower = sum(Power1) + sum(Power2) by BatchNumber
| where BatchNumber != data_BatchNumber_of_max_Timestamp_mv
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. However, I am currently having a problem with the materialize-view. In your first step, you created an empty table. In my case, I have the data already being streamed as mentioned in the description because values are coming in real time. So what I did is that I projected all these columns like you did in step 1 but in my case I saved them in a view. However, for the next step I can't create a materialize view from the view that I created. It is not showing me the syntax, as if kusto doesn't under the expression .create . What is the issue here ?

Comment: (1) "Materialized views expose an aggregation query over a source **table**, or over another materialized view."  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/materialized-views/materialized-view-overview  (2) Check out `backfill` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/materialized-views/materialized-view-create#examples

Comment: This is hardly making any sense... A cluster holds databases. A database holds tables. A table holds data. Someone ingests data to that table. The materialize views is defined up-on that table.

Comment: "The create operation requires Database Admin permissions" https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/materialized-views/materialized-view-create

Comment: Thank you so much for you help... I hope that I can get this access ! Sorry for all these question :)

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have the admin rights so I won't be able to create table, materialized-views or my own functions. Is there a second possibility to achieve this outcome without using materialized-views? Maybe using let statements, creating views and using summarize ?

Comment: Organizational politics are out of scope for SO :-)

Comment: There is no way of resolving it without Materialized-Views :( ?

Comment: Depends on what exactly you're trying to achieve. The code used for the MV and function can be executed as  a query, but that means that every time you execute the query, you are going to scan the whole data again and again.

Comment: That is okay for me. As long as it works that is fine. How will we have to adapt the code above ?

Comment: See updated answer